# How do I receive the event message from Azure Functions to get the content in a WebApp?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I use this BlobTrigger in c# to see, if there are changes in the blob. This sounds find, but how can I send this message from the Azure Function BlobTrigger to my Webapp? For example I want to display the "Name" of the blob, which was detected by the Azure Function on the html site (which is the WebApp) for Endusers. I did search but can't found the good answer. At the moment I can only output the message on the Console, but not sending this to any WebEndpoints. Would be great if someone can share his experiences.

```
    [FunctionName("BlobTriggerCSharp")]        
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}")] Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
}
```

Comment: I was curious about the REST API to reach out the Blobstorage, is this only possible when using HTTPTrigger in Azure Functions? How can I updated the information on my webapps, which is connected to the blobstorage. Do you also use REST API or Azure Functions? Which is a better solution?

Comment: just do a post to your api passing the parameter name in the request

Comment: can you show me some codes? Thanks

Comment: I am not very clear about your problem, can you describe it in detail? According to my own understanding, if your web app has a corresponding interface, you can call this interface using `HttpClient`.

Comment: Hi Frank Gong, I save the data on blobstorage and want to display it on the webapp. Means if someone uploaded a file on blob, the webapp will catch the file and show it on the site.